# A four digit number using exact same 4 digits

Tags: no-computers, formation-of-numbers, alphametic

ABCD is a 4 digit number where A,B,C and D are 4 distinctly separate digits between 1 and 9.

Using any of the following math operations and the digits A,B,C and D exactly once get the number ABCD.

Math operations allowed: **+ - x / ^ ! Square root and parenthesis**. NO concatenation.
There are at least 2 solutions. So answer with the use of the *least number* of math operations gets the tick.

Please no programming.

Comment: To be clear $(4-2)^{10}$ is not allowed?

Comment: The 10 in the exponent is forbidden in capital letters, seems pretty clear.

Comment: @Bass is correct. Number 10 is not part of 1 to 9 digits.

Comment: I immediately thought of $(5-0!+4-0!)! = 5040$ but that violates both the no zero rule and that A,B,C,D are distinct. And $4^{(1+2)!-0!} = 4^5 = 1024$ is another with zero.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis since we're looking for the solution with the least number of operators, it seems unlikely that the factorial and the square root are involved; we need to go from four separate numbers into only one, and unary operations don't change the number of numbers we have.

Comment: I voted to close this as underspecified to try to prevent it accumulating more and more answers which have different optimal solutions.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_number. I remember writing some BASIC code on an Amstrad CPC464 to find some in the early 90s after some issue of the "Science et Vie" French magazine mentioned them (they called them *nombre autodigital* there).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On par with Bass, with preservation of digit order:

> $5^5=3125\implies(3\times1+2)^5=3125$

Another, this time with reverse digit order:

> $(6*1*9)^2=2916$

Comment: No, no, this is clearly better than mine, since it preserves the digit order.

Comment: Yes indeed @Daniel Mathias. And I just found a solution with factorials involved.

Answer (score 16):

In order and very brief

> $4096 = 4^{0^9+6}$

... and also illegal since it contains a zero. Thanks @Bass.

If we are allowed parentheses to mean binomial coefficients:

> $6435 = \begin{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} \\ 3+5 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: This is so beautiful OP should immediately change the rules to lift the ban on zeroes.

Comment: I agree, zero is not evil.

Answer (score 10):

Unless parens count as an operation, this should be optimal:

> $(\frac{8}{2}-1)^7 = 2187$

(Of course I'll be keeping an eye out for a solution without parens, and with the digits in the correct order, but that might take a while.)

Here's one without parens, so this is definitely minimal in terms of operations:

> $6\times4^5+1 = 6145$

Doesn't have the digit order style points though. After trying pretty much all of the likely candidates, and many unlikely ones too, I'm going to call it: I don't think there is a three operation solution without parens that has the digits in the correct order.

Comment: Definitely one of the two solutions I had @Bass. I would be interested in knowing how you got there.

Comment: @DrD looked for any x^y with four distinct digits ABCD, then tried to make x and y out of A,B,C and D. Seemed easiest to do any maths while still in single digits.

Comment: You can get the first in order with a minor modification (2+1^8)^7.

Answer (score 3):

No fancy ordering.

> $1296 = 6^{\frac{9-1}{2}}$

Answer (score 3):

How about:

> $ 8192 = 2^{{\sqrt{9}}! - 1 + 8} $

Nobody has been using the monadic operations, so I did.

Comment: $8^{1+\sqrt 9} \times 2$ is in order and uses fewer operations.

Answer (score 2):

using factorial (!) is a great help to make big numbers using a simple digit num... Based on this, we can find the following answers:

In correct order:

> $2163 = (2-1+6!)*3 $

> $5167 = 5! + 1 + 6 + 7!$

> $4368 = (\sqrt{4}*3)* (6!+8)$

No ordering:

> $3625 = (6!+5)*(3+2)$

> $5761 =7!+6!+1^5$

Comment: These do use more math operations then the minimum, so they are not optimal, and optimal solutions have already been posted